# Proof verification for a question about a ring of sets in $\Omega$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\scrD}{\mathscr{D}} \newcommand{\scrR}{\mathscr{R}}$
**Problem:** Let $\scrR$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ and let $\scrD$ be the collection of all finite unions of sets of the form
$$
R_1 \cap R_2 \cap \dots \cap R_n \cap R_{n+1}^c \cap \dots \cap R_{n+p}^c (\star)
$$
where $R_i \in \scrR, n \geq 1, p \geq 0$. I want to show that $\scrD$ is a ring in $\Omega$.

> **Definition:** A collection of subsets $\mathscr{A}$ of a set $\Omega$ is a **ring** if it is closed under subtractions and unions.

It's a bit of a lengthy answer but does the logic work here?

> *Attempt:* First we show that if $E,F$ are any two sets of the form in $(\star)$ then $E \setminus F$ is an element of $\scrD$. Let
> $$
> E = R_1 \cap \dots \cap R_n \cap R_{n+1}^c \cap \dots \cap R_{n+p}^c, \text{ and } F = S_1 \cap \dots \cap S_m \cap S_{m+1}^c \cap \dots \cap S_{m+q}^c.
> $$
> Then
> \begin{align}
> E \setminus F & = E \cap (S_1 \cap \dots \cap S_m \cap S_{m+1}^c \cap \dots \cap S_{m+q}^c)^c \\
> &= E \cap (S_1^c \cup \dots \cup S_m^c \cup S_{m+1} \cup \dots \cup S_{m+q})\\
> & = (S_1^c \cap E) \cup \dots \cup (S_m^c \cap E) \cup \dots \cup (S_{m+q} \cap E) \\
> &=(R_1 \cap \dots \cap R_n \cap R_{n+1}^c \cap \dots \cap R_{n+p}^c \cap S_1^c) \cup \dots \cup ( R_1 \cap \dots \cap R_n \cap R_{n+1}^c \cap \dots \cap R_{n+p}^c \cap S_m^c) \cup \dots \cup ( S_{m+q} \cap R_1 \cap \dots \cap R_n \cap R_{n+1}^c \cap \dots \cap R_{n+p}^c).
> \end{align}
> And each of these sets is of the form $(\star)$ where we have rearranged the order due to the commutativity of unions and intersections. Therefore $E \setminus F$ is a finite union of sets of the form $(\star)$ and so $E \setminus F \in \scrD$. Next we show that $\scrD$ is closed under intersections, so let $D_1,D_2 \in \scrD$, this means that
> $$
> D_1 = \bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k \text{ and } D_2 = \bigcup_{j=1}^m F_j
> $$
> where $E_k$ and $F_j$ are sets of the form in $(\star)$. Then
> \begin{align}
> D_1 \cap D_2 & = \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k \right) \cap \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^m F_j \right) \\
> &= \bigcup_{k=1}^n \bigcup_{j=1}^m E_k \cap F_j.
> \end{align}
> Because $E_k,F_j$ are of the form in $(\star)$ it is obvious that $E_k \cap F_j$ is also of the form in $(\star)$ and so $D_1 \cap D_2)$ is a finite union of sets of the form $(\star)$ and so $D_1 \cap D_2 \in \scrD$. Now we can show that $\scrD$ is in fact a ring, note that if $D_1,D_2 \in \scrD$ and
> $$
> D_1 = \bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k \text{ and } D_2 = \bigcup_{j=1}^m F_j
> $$
> it is evident that $D_1 \cup D_2 \in \scrD$ since we have a finite union of sets of the form $(\star)$. It remains to show closure under subtractions, note that
> \begin{align}
> D_1 \setminus D_2 & = D_1 \cap D_2^c \\
> & = \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k\right) \cap \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^m F_j^c \right) \\
> &= \bigcup_{k=1}^n \left[ \bigcap_{j=1}^m E_k \cap F_j^c \right] \\
> & = \bigcup_{k=1}^n \left[ \bigcap_{j=1}^m E_k\setminus F_j\right].
> \end{align}
> Because we showed the subtraction of two sets of the form $(\star)$ are in $\scrD$ it follows that $E_k \setminus F_j$ is an element of $\scrD$, we also showed that $\scrD$ is closed under finite unions so that for every $1 \leq k \leq n$ the sets $\cap_{j=1}^m E_k \setminus F_j$ are elements of $\scrD$ and so $D_1 \setminus D_2$ is a finite union of sets of the form in $\scrD$ and so $D_1 \setminus D_2 \in \scrD$ and $\scrD$ is a ring in $\Omega$.

Please let me if there are any glaring errors I've missed, (probable, I was excited to have an actual solution idea so this might have been done too quickly) and if it's alright are there any more efficient approaches I could have taken?